# SQL "%" equivalent in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Is there any SQL equivalent of "%" sign in VBA?
I need to return a few files just with some characters in the middle.

Help really appreciated!

For instance here is my code: I need to download all file that has in the name 2013 from that webpage and save and call them differently. Is this mission possible?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim strURL As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim i As Integer

    strURL = "http://cetatenie.just.ro/wp-content/uploads/Ordin-********.2013.pdf"

    strPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\ee28118\Desktop\178.pdf"

    Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, strURL, strPath, 0, 0)

    If Ret = 0 Then
        MsgBox "File successfully downloaded"
    Else
        MsgBox "Unable to download the file"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you navigate to the uploads folder, you get a directory listing of all the files in it. You can loop through the hyperlinks on that listing and test each to see if it meets your criterion and, if so, download it.  You need a reference to MSXML and MSHTML.  Here's an example.

```
Sub Sample()

    Dim sUrl As String
    Dim xHttp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Dim hDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim hAnchor As MSHTML.HTMLAnchorElement
    Dim Ret As Long
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim i As Long

    sPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\ee28118\Desktop\"
    sUrl = "http://cetatenie.just.ro/wp-content/uploads/"

    'Get the directory listing
    Set xHttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    xHttp.Open "GET", sUrl
    xHttp.send

    'Wait for the page to load
    Do Until xHttp.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    'Put the page in an HTML document
    Set hDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    hDoc.body.innerHTML = xHttp.responseText

    'Loop through the hyperlinks on the directory listing
    For i = 0 To hDoc.getElementsByTagName("a").Length - 1
        Set hAnchor = hDoc.getElementsByTagName("a").Item(i)

        'test the pathname to see if it matches your pattern
        If hAnchor.pathname Like "Ordin-*.2013.pdf" Then
            Ret = UrlDownloadToFile(0, sUrl & hAnchor.pathname, sPath, 0, 0)

            If Ret = 0 Then
                Debug.Print sUrl & hAnchor.pathname & " downloaded to " & sPath
            Else
                Debug.Print sUrl & hAnchor.pathname & " not downloaded"
            End If
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

**Edit**

I assumed that URLDownloadToFile was already written.  I didn't write one, I just used the below function to test the code that iterates through the files.  You can use it to make sure the above code works for you, but you'll need to write the actual code to download the file eventually. With all the arguments to URLDownloadToFile, I'm surprised it doesn't exist already.

```
Function UrlDownloadToFile(lNum As Long, sUrl As String, sPath As String, lNum1 As Long, lNum2 As Long) As Long

    UrlDownloadToFile = 0

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you but I am very beginner at this, may I ask for a hint on MSXML and MSHTML reference? What shall I do? Thank you!

Comment: OK I think I managed to install both of them but afterwards I get the Error: "Sub or Function not defined" highlighting (URLDownloadToFile) and the name of Macro... any suggestions?

Comment: URLDownloadToFile came from your code. I assumed you had some method of downloading a file given the URL and that you had created a function called URLDownloadToFile to do it. For now, add a function with that name (see edit to my answer) and then, if you don't know how to download a file through vba, start a new question.

Comment: @user2087878 Dont post multiple question for one problem.

Comment: I didn't realize URLDownloadToFile is a win API function.  I answered the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641717/download-files-pdf-from-web/15644851#15644851 to address it. I don't think it's a problem that they're in two questions, although this one would be better title 'How to iterate through files in a web folder that match a pattern'

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Like Operator.

Characters in pattern Matches in string

```
? Any single character. 
* Zero or more characters. 
# Any single digit (0–9). 
[charlist] Any single character in charlist. 
[!charlist] Any single character not in charlist
```

Example :

```
Dim MyCheck
MyCheck = "aBBBa" Like "a*a"    ' Returns True.
MyCheck = "F" Like "[A-Z]"    ' Returns True.
MyCheck = "F" Like "[!A-Z]"    ' Returns False.
MyCheck = "a2a" Like "a#a"    ' Returns True.
MyCheck = "aM5b" Like "a[L-P]#[!c-e]"    ' Returns True.
MyCheck = "BAT123khg" Like "B?T*"    ' Returns True.
MyCheck = "CAT123khg" Like "B?T*"    ' Returns False.
```

Comment: Can I use it to download more files from a webpage using this approach that have only Date that is different in their name?

Comment: i.e.   strURL = "http://cetatenie.just.ro/wp-content/uploads/Ordin-********.2013.pdf"

Comment: doubtful, I don't know if you can do a wildcard file search on an FTP server?

Answer (score 2):

Try below code : The boolean function would return true if the string has the string **2013** in it.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim result As Boolean
    result = has2013("http://cetatenie.just.ro/wp-content/uploads/Ordin-********.2013.pdf")
    Debug.Print result
    result = has2013("http://cetatenie.just.ro/wp-content/uploads/Ordin-********.2014.pdf")
    Debug.Print result
End Sub

Function has2013(lnk As String) As Boolean
    has2013 = lnk Like "*2013*"
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

in VBA use the LIKE function with wildcard characters:

here is an example (copied from [Ozgrid Forums](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=23047&p=116719#post116719))

```
Dim sht As Worksheet 
For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 
    If sht.Name Like "FRI*" Then 
         'Add code for Friday sheets
    Else 
        If sht.Name Like "MON*" Then 
             'Add code for Monday sheets
        End If 
    End If 
Next
```

The multiplication character * takes the place of zero or more characters, whereas **?** takes the place of exactly 1 character, and **#** takes the place of 1 number. There are other more specific char. matching strategies if you only want to match certain characters.

so there you go!

Also, you could take a look at [Ozgrid Forums: Using Regular Expressions in VBA](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=37624&p=187752#post187752)

To get a list of the files on the server, read up on FTP (using DIR) at [Mr Excel - List files using FTP](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/491558-list-files-via-ftp.html)

Comment: Maybe you can have a tip also on the code I added above.Thank you!

Comment: I doubt that would work, you need to use your wildcards to search all the available files on the server/FTP server, then loop through them doanloading each one