# The macro that opens/saves a file from website

Tags: vba

I am trying to create a macro in VBA that will open or save a .docx file from a website. As a sample, I am using this website: https://www.duxburysystems.com/documentation/dbt12.4/samples/word/samples.htm

I would like open or save for instance the file: albanian-sq.docx.

Here is my code that I created but it doesn't work:

```
Sub test()


Dim myURL As String
myURL = "https://www.duxburysystems.com/documentation/dbt12.4/samples/word/samples.htm/albanian.sq.docx"

Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, "username", "password"
WinHttpReq.send

If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile "C:\Users\Arerox\Desktop\albanian.sq.docx", 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
    oStream.Close
End If

End Sub
```

Could you please advise?

Just opening the file would be enough. Saving is not required.

Thanks,

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Does an error box pop up and say "it doesn't work"?

Comment: There is no pop-up. The code works but nothing happens.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download Files (PDF) from Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641717/download-files-pdf-from-web)